# Reading all the latest measured values of a measuring device

Tags: sql, t-sql, azure-sql-database

I have a table which looks like that:

```
id | date             | device_id | measurement_id | value
---+------------------+-----------+----------------+------
1  | 2020-02-24 20:00 | 3         | 1              | 7.9
2  | 2020-02-24 20:00 | 3         | 2              | 3.2
3  | 2020-02-24 20:00 | 3         | 3              | 5.12
4  | 2020-02-24 20:00 | 1         | 1              | 7.9
5  | 2020-02-24 20:00 | 1         | 2              | 3.2
6  | 2020-02-24 20:00 | 1         | 3              | 5.12
7  | 2020-02-24 20:10 | 1         | 1              | 15.2
8  | 2020-02-24 20:10 | 1         | 2              | 5.8
9  | 2020-02-24 20:10 | 1         | 3              | 9.1
10 | 2020-02-24 20:10 | 2         | 1              | 4.6
11 | 2020-02-24 20:10 | 2         | 2              | 2.3
12 | 2020-02-24 20:20 | 1         | 4              | 45.1
```

Now I want to read the latest value of each **measurement_id** depending on the **device_id**. So in this example (for **device_id** 1):

```
id | date             | device_id | measurement_id | value
---+------------------+-----------+----------------+------
7  | 2020-02-24 20:10 | 1         | 1              | 15.2
8  | 2020-02-24 20:10 | 1         | 2              | 5.8
9  | 2020-02-24 20:10 | 1         | 3              | 9.1
12 | 2020-02-24 20:20 | 1         | 4              | 45.1
```

How can I best realize this with T-SQL on Azure SQL Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the right indexes, a correlated subquery often has the best performance:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.device = 1 and
      t.date = (select max(t2.date) 
                from t t2 
                where t2.device_id = t.device_id and
                      t2.measurement_id = t.measurement_id
               );
```

The index you want is on `(device_id, measurement_id, date)`.

The canonical solution uses `row_number()` and works almost as well.

Comment: In my use case the table has several million records and a single device (device_id) has about 650 different fields at measurement_id. The SQL query takes about 3 seconds with the index suggested by you. Do you think this can be improved? I ask because in the next step the device_id has to be filtered. Would you filter outside or inside the device_id? Is the correlation of device_id between the outer and inner table still necessary?

Comment: @A.Fendt . . . Is the query any faster using `row_number()`?  If you need to filter by device, then filter in the `where` clause.  The correlation clause takes care of the subquery.

Comment: What do you mean when you say if the query is faster than `row_number()`? Do you mean the query from @CR7SMS? Because the query from him is much slower.

Comment: @A.Fendt . . . Your observation is consistent with my experience.  `row_number()` is a fine solution, but `exists` can be more optimized.

Comment: What do you mean with `exists`? This does not appear in your query nor in the query of @CR7SMS?

Comment: @A.Fendt . . . I meant a correlated subquery.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the row_number function to get the latest record for each device ID and measurement ID:

```
select a.*
from
(select *,
       row_number() over(partition by device_id,measurement_id order by date desc) as rownum
from table) a
where a.rownum=1
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, did not test it...

```
select * 
from my_table mt1 
where mt1.date = (select max(mt2.date) 
                   from my_table mt2 
                   where mt2.device_id = mt1.device_id 
                   and  mt2.measurement_id = mt1.measurement_id
                   )
```

Answer (score 1):

Please Run this code bellow, I tested and it works well, filter the `device_id=1`:

```
select * from dbo.test11 where value IN (
    select Max(value) FROM 
            (select * from test11 where device_id=1) tb2  group by tb2.measurement_id
        )
```

Create the table contains the same data with you:

[image]

Execute the query and get the result:

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your solution but the approach to filter by value is very slow on my database with millions of records and also wrong because other records have the same value.

Answer (score 0):

A pretty simple one.
You will want to use both the MAX statement and the GroupBy clause.
Give it a try and if you need more specific examples I can help you out.

-Matt-